# Is it possible to run google app script to submit a html form from website to google sheet on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am now trying to create a form block for user to input info and submit files.

I use Google Sheet with Google Apps Script when I test it, everything works fine when I test it on desktop browser, but never work on mobile browser of Chrome IOS, and Safari.

Could anyone give me some hints how to make the `doPost()` method work on mobile browser.

Here is my script from Google Apps Script:

```
var emailTo= "420@gmail.com"
var REDIRECT_URL = "/successful";

function doPost(e) {

try {
var data = e.parameter.fileContent;
var filename = e.parameter.filename;
var email = e.parameter.email;
var name = e.parameter.name;
var result=uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data,filename,name,email,e);
return redirect();
} catch(error) { // if error return this
Logger.log(error);
return ContentService
.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
}

// new property service GLOBAL
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
// see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/

/**
* select the sheet
*/
function setup() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}

/**
* record_data inserts the data received from the html form submission
* e is the data received from the POST
*/

function record_data(e,fileUrl) {
try {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('test'); // select the responses sheet

var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
var row = [ new Date() ]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp
// loop through the header columns
for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column

if(headers[i].length > 0 && headers[i] == "photo-link") {
row.push(fileUrl); // add data to row
}
else if(headers[i].length > 0) {
row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]); // add data to row
}
}
// more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
}
catch(error) {
Logger.log(e);
}
finally {
return;
}

}

function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, name, email,e) {
try {
var dropbox = "Shop-Clients-Pics";
var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

if (folders.hasNext()) {
folder = folders.next();
} else {
folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}

var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file);
var file = folder.createFolder([name, email].join("-")).createFile(blob);

var fileUrl=file.getUrl();

//Generating Email Body
var html =
'<body>' +
'<h2> Test Auto Send Email </h2>' +
'<p>Name : '+e.parameters.name+'</p>' +
'<p>Email : '+e.parameters.email+'</p>' +
'<p>Contact : '+e.parameters.contact+'</p>' +
'<p>Address : '+e.parameters.address+'</p>' +
'<p>LinkedIn Url : '+e.parameters.linkedinUrl+'</p>' +
'<p>File Name : '+e.parameters.filename+'</p>' +
'<p><a href='+file.getUrl()+'>Resume Link</a></p><br />' +
'</body>';

record_data(e,fileUrl);

MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, "Test Auto Send Email322","Test Auto Send Email Recieved322",{htmlBody:html});
return file.getUrl();
} catch (f) {
return ContentService // return json success results
.createTextOutput(
JSON.stringify({"result":"file upload failed",
"data": JSON.stringify(f) }))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
}
function redirect() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    "<script>window.top.location.href=\"" + REDIRECT_URL + "\";</script>"
  ); 
}
```

For More Info: My function of submitting the file:

```
function UploadFile() {
var reader = new FileReader();
var file = document.getElementById('attach').files[0];
reader.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('fileContent').value=reader.result;
document.getElementById('filename').value=file.name;
document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit();
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

I got an error when I use Chrome mobile:

> LOG TransportError: There was an error during the transport or processing of this request. Error code = 7, Path = /wardeninit

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console? [This doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging?hl=en) might help if you don't have console on mobile

Comment: There is an error says ``` LOG TransportError: There was an error during the transport or processing of this request. Error code = 7, Path = /wardeninit ```

Comment: And here is my function of upload files:
function UploadFile() {
var reader = new FileReader();
var file = document.getElementById('attach').files[0];
reader.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('fileContent').value=reader.result;
document.getElementById('filename').value=file.name;
document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit();
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

Comment: You should add those things to the original question, to make StackOverflow better - i'll have a look in the meantime, if I find anything, i'll let you know

Comment: Okay...will do, thank you for helping.

Comment: Where are you hosting from?

Comment: Im now hosting on webflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220496/discussion-between-iansedano-and-kenken).

Comment: That error probably means nothing. Check for errors in the console when you upload